# SSIS: ADO.NET Informix source doesn't work with temp table

Tags: ssis, informix

I'm trying to create SSIS package to perform a relativwely simple ETL.

My connection manager  is DB2 .Net provider (.Net Providers/IBM DB2 .NET Data Priovider).

My data source is ADO NET Source. It's working in SQL command mode.

Following command works:

```
select first 10 *
from part
```

But this doesn't work:

```
select first 10 *
from part
into temp temp2;

select * 
from temp2;

drop temp table temp2;
```

Actually it behaves pretty odd.
After first execution (press button 'Preview...') I usually get this error:

```
Pipeline component has returned HRESULT error code 0xC02020FE from a method call. (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)
```

After second execution (press button 'Preview...' again) I get the data set!

However, after third execution (and consecutive executions) the error tells that...

```
ERROR [IX000] [IBM][IDS/UNIX64] Temp table (temp3) already exists in session. (IBM.Data.DB2)
```

Googling leads me nowhere :(

Is there any logic behind this, and how to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

After encapsulating the query in the STORED PROCEDURE and calling it using EXECUTE PROCEDURE like this...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_DATA()
RETURNING CHAR(256), CHAR(256);

DEFINE l_fld1 CHAR(256);
DEFINE l_fld2 CHAR(256);

SELECT first 10 fld1, fld2
FROM part
INTO TEMP temp2;

FOREACH
SELECT fld1, fld2
INTO l_fld1, l_fld2
FROM temp2

RETURN l_fld1, l_fld2
WITH RESUME;

END FOREACH

DROP TEMP TABLE temp2;

END PROCEDURE
```

...I have a few new problems:

- after clicking "Preview..." first I get result and on ther second click I get `ERROR [IX000] [IBM][IDS/UNIX64] Temp table (otkalcec.temp2) already exists in session.`
- if I wait a little bit and click "Preview..." again, it works again; obviously the session is dropped in the meantime (some idle timeout?)
- nevertheless, query always returns with empty fieldnames and that may be the cause I don't have any columns mapped when i choose "Columns" on the left :(

**UPDATE 2:**

There was a problem related to the SSIS consuming Informix driver parameter which I didn't know it existed: "Connection lifetime". This solves first two problems.

Now the preview resultset works fine. The only problem I have is missing column information in Columns. Everything seems to be working except THAT, and I can't proceed without freaking column information! >:(

Comment: Are you sure that the program disconnects from the databaseserver, so that the session is destroyed? Normally all temp tables will be destroyed as soon as the database session terminates. After terminating the program, check this again to be sure
that the session is destroyed.

Comment: I think to troubleshoot your first error you need to perform debugging steps, to get more insight what happening before the error 0xC02020FE in your package.

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde: regarding the first question, temp table lifetime is restricted to the session duration, but my knowledge of SSIS session management underneath the hood is very limited. AFAIK, the thing is opaque and can vary across different drivers :( There is only one "RetainSameConnection", flag, set to false, so the connection (and session to go with) should in theory be dropped...

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde: regarding the second observation, the error disappeared when I used STORED PROCEDURE to wrap the query. However, there are new problems now. Updating my question.

Comment: Have a look for this Killing sessions automatically with SSIS : http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/killing-sessions-automatically-with-ssis/#comments

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde: this is related to SSAS sessions, right?

Comment: The article is for SSIS!

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde: Article explains how to kill SSAS sessions using SSIS package. It is explicitly states using SSAS 2008 DM views. Actually it solves the problem of killing naughty clients (funny intro :D) that pull tremendous ammount of data from AS cube. Anyway, I managed to solve that one without workarounds. The only problem I have is lack of metadata that should have been collected by SSIS, but they are not. See my updated question.